# How do you map a c# abstract class to Rust?

Tags: c#, rust, traits

Possibly a poorly worded question, but here goes an example:

given these structs;

```
pub struct Poll {
    _lat: f64,
    _lon: f64,
    _at: i64,
    _heading: f64,
    _speed: f64,
}

pub struct Waypoint {
    _lat: f64,
    _lon: f64,
}
```

and this trait;

```
pub trait CoordMeasure {
    fn dist_to(&self, other: &Self ) -> f64;
}
```

how do I avoid duplicating this code like I have done?

```
impl CoordMeasure for Poll {
    fn dist_to(&self, other: &Poll) -> f64 {
        super::core::distance(self, other)
    }
}

impl CoordMeasure for Waypoint {
    fn dist_to(&self, other: &Waypoint) -> f64 {
        super::core::distance(self, other)
    }
}
```

I have two calls to the same function distance.

```
pub fn distance<T: Coord>(a: &T, b: &T ) -> f64 {
        let lat1_rads = (90.0 - a.lat()).to_radians();
        let lat2_rads = (90.0 - b.lat()).to_radians();
        let lon_rads = (b.lon() - a.lon()).to_radians();

        let cos_of_lat1 = lat1_rads.cos();
        let cos_of_lat2 = lat2_rads.cos();

        let sin_of_lat1 = lat1_rads.sin();
        let sin_of_lat2 = lat2_rads.sin();

        let cos_of_lons = lon_rads.cos();
        let equation = ((cos_of_lat2 * cos_of_lat1) + (sin_of_lat2 * sin_of_lat1 *    cos_of_lons)).acos();
        6334009.6 * equation
}
```

It's just one line of code that's being repeated, but it could be more in a better example. In C# this code would be written once in an abstract class that Waypoint and Poll were derived from. What's the idiomatic [Rust](http://www.rust-lang.org/) way of handling this situation?

Comment: Rust convention does not have leading underscores in the field names. Unless you mark them `pub` they are private anyway; there is really no good reason to use a leading underscore.

Comment: What is `super::core::distance`? It’s evidently generic, but over what?

Comment: Over anything with a lat long. Be it a naked waypoint or GPS poll that has speed and distance or even a scheduled waypoint that has a schedule time, estimated time and actual time.

Comment: Distance is just the great circle calculation between two things with a lot long.

Comment: So that’s another trait; what’s different about `CoordMeasure`? (It’d be good to see all relevant definitions, and that includes `distance` and its trait bounds.)

Comment: I added distance into the question. I think all the relevant pieces are there.

Comment: So why does `CoordMeasure` even exist? Are you just wanting it to be implemented for all things that implement `Coord`?

Comment: Yes, CoordMeasure exists so that a struct implementing the trait Coord has a convenient function to return the measure of the distance in meters from itself to another Coord. I realize that `let d = x.dist_to(y)` is the same as `let d = distance(x, y)`. I was thinking the former was better form.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62936/discussion-between-bruce-and-chris-morgan).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generic implementations are possible:

```
impl<T: Coord> CoordMeasure for T {
    fn dist_to(&self, other: &T) -> f64 {
        super::core::distance(self, other)
    }
}
```

But in this particular case, you should just drop `CoordMeasure` altogether and implement this on `Coord` as a default method:

```
trait Coord {
    …
    fn dist_to(&self, other: &Self) -> f64 {
        super::core::distance(self, other)  // or move its contents in here
    }
}
```

You might also want to make it so that it can cope with other types of `other` (I don’t see any immediate reason why `other` must be the same type as `self`:

```
fn dist_to<Other: Coord>(&self, other: &Other) -> f64 {
    let lat1_rads = (90.0 - self.lat()).to_radians();
    let lat2_rads = (90.0 - other.lat()).to_radians();
    let lon_rads = (b.lon() - self.lon()).to_radians();

    let cos_of_lat1 = lat1_rads.cos();
    let cos_of_lat2 = lat2_rads.cos();

    let sin_of_lat1 = lat1_rads.sin();
    let sin_of_lat2 = lat2_rads.sin();

    let cos_of_lons = lon_rads.cos();
    let equation = ((cos_of_lat2 * cos_of_lat1) + (sin_of_lat2 * sin_of_lat1 *    cos_of_lons)).acos();
    6334009.6 * equation
}
```

Comment: Ah!! I didn't realize a trait could contain more than definitions of functions. Perfect.

Comment: this is cool,  but how can I add member values into a trait in this way, if I see it as an abstract class?

Comment: @Mr.WangfromNextDoor: your question doesn’t make sense as you’ve expressed it, but I can tell it’s not relevant here. If you desire to ask something, ask a new question.